# Unable to connect to Aurora MySql with Aws ECS fargate container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-fargate

I have a .net core 3.1 application which is deployed as docker container on AWS Ecs with fargate. I'd created 2 new Aurora MySql dbs and tried to connect to one of the db cluster by using the writer endpoint. Now the issue is when I try to call the POST method through postman by calling load balancer DNS, I am getting the following exception:

> "An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient
>   failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding
>   'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call."

I'd also tried adding retry pattern as mentioned in the exception but no luck.
I've allowed Aurora/MySql on port 3306 from anywhere in my security group which I created for RDS. I'd also added Aurora/MySql on port 3306 for source "My cluster service security group and also load balancer security group" but even then no luck. Finally I added All traffic on all ports from anywhere but even then the error was same. So I suspect it's something different.
I've then tried running the application through the docker desktop on my windows but I still got the same error there.

> An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server
>   'db-cluster.cluster-cqb2jskhx78p.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com'.

My Connection string is:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=db-cluster.cluster-cqb2jskhx78p.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Initial Catalog=demodb;User ID=admin;Password=MyPassword;port=3306"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty hard to troubleshoot fargate container out of the box. The first things you should check:

- Are RDS and the Containers in the same VPC?
- Does the RDS security group have the correct port open to the container's security group?

A few options for troubleshooting:

- The quickest option, deploy an EC2 instance in the same subnet as your container and troubleshoot the connection with that
- In a dev environment only, install SSH on your container via the entrypoint script.

  - Alternatively, have a separate task which launches a container running only SSH for networking troubleshooting
- Use a container host for Dev so you can use docker exec